How to reflect in the line $y=x+4$?
I've recently come across this question in my book. It basically says that there are some points, $ABCDEF$ of certain coordinates and I need to find the coordinates of the reflected image on the line $y=x+4$. I don't even really know what to do. Am I supposed to take it as a typical $y=x$ reflection then add $+4$ to the $y$ coordinate?

I suggest you read this : https://martin-thoma.com/reflecting-a-point-over-a-line/

The reflection of a point A through the line $y=x+4$ is equivalent to the reflection of A through the line $y=x$ followed by the translation of $4$ units left and $4$ units up.
That is,
$A(a,b)\xrightarrow[y=x+4]{\text{Reflection}}A'(b-4,a+4)$.
In matrix form,
$\begin{pmatrix}
a \\
b 
\end{pmatrix}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
a \\
b 
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}
-4 \\
4 
\end{pmatrix}$
In other words, swap its $x$ and $y$ coordinates, then subtract $4$ from the $x$ coordinate and add $4$ to the $y$ coordinate to get the coordinate of the reflected point.
Hope it helps!

Thank you SO SO much!

You're welcome!

Given a Cartesian coordinate system $(x,y);$
consider a new coordinate system $(x',y')$
$y'=y-4$ and $x=x'$, a translation.
A point $(a, b)$ in the original $(x,y)$ system corresponds to
$(a, b-4)$ in $(x'y')$.
Reflect $(a, b-4)$ in the system  $(x'y') $
about  $y'=x' $;
which results in $(b-4,a).$
And now back to the original
$(x,y)$ system
$x=b-4,$ $y=a+4.$
Altogether
$(a, b)$ reflection  $(b-4,a+4)$

Thank you! Both this answer and that of @Pustam Raut were very helpful

Most welcome, Peter

If there is a point $A=(a,b)$ and you want to reflect it through the line $y=x+4$, you can first suppose that the reflected point is $A'=(c,d)$ and notice that $(\frac{a+c}{2},\frac{b+d}{2})$ is on the line $y=x+4$. Also，the line $AA'$ is perpendicular to $y=x+4$, you get another equation: $\frac{b-d}{a-c}=-1$. Two equations, two variables and you can get $c$ and $d$. Solving $\{b+d=a+c+8,\ b-d=c-a\}$, we get $c=b-4,\ d=a+4$.
So, the reflected coordinate of $(a,b)$ is $(b-4,a+4)$.

Alternative method: Equation of the perpendicular bisector of the line $y=x+4$ through the point $A(a,b)$ is $y-b=-x+a$. Both intersect at the point $B\left(\frac{a+b}{2}-2,\frac{a+b}{2}+2\right)$. The required reflected point $A'$ divides $AB$ in the ratio $2:1$ externally. So, it is given by the external section formula: $A'\left(2\cdot\frac{a+b}{2}-4-a,2\cdot\frac{a+b}{2}+4-b\right)\equiv A'(b-4,a+4)$.
